# What does this method return?

Tags: java

I have just started learning to program. I was wondering what this method returns:

```
public int doSomething(int size) {

   int[] b = new int [size];
   int c = 0;

   for (int d : b) {

       c = c + d;
   }

    return c;
 }
```

Comment: It returns the *sum* of all the elements in the array.

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: Compile it and run it and you will see..

Comment: Zero.  Try and figure out why :-)

Comment: -5? It's deeper than that. The fact that the array elements are initialised to zero is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing adding in the array and  the `c` value is  still `zero`.

You might confused with the line

```
for (int d : b) {
```

That is java [`for each loop`](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html).

Answer (score 1):

Two crucial things:

1. `int[] b = new int [size];` will initialise every element in the array to zero.
2. `for (int d : b)` notation iterates over every element in the array.

So the computation is summing the elements of the array with answer zero.

(Note that in C and C++ arrays elements are not initialised to zero and the behaviour of a similar construct in those languages would be undefined).

Answer (score 0):

The cycle accumulates the sum of the values in the array `b` into the variable `c`. As an integer is set to `0` by default and you never change the values of the elements in `b`, the sum of `size` zeros is still zero and thus `c` is 0 when it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You have blank array - default zeros as it is int array - So currently it is returning zero. Add some numbers in array you will get their addition in returned c.

```
public int doSomething(int size) {

   int[] b = new int [size];

   b[0]=5; // add integers like this to get non zero return
   b[1]=8;
   .
   .
   b[size-1]=3;


   int c = 0;

   for (int d : b) {

       c = c + d;
   }

    return c;
 }
```